# Mounting won't work: bad magic number on newly created partition, none of the rescue blocks work

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, filesystem, ext4, fdisk

Good Day everyone. This is my first question.

So I have this drive from an old RAID-System with 2.7TB of storage and I want to use it for some regular ext4 partitions:

```
root@FluxCapacitor:/dev# fdisk -l /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3F869CBE-740E-1940-A549-5FA3E087B04D
```

If I partition the drive I get:

```
Device          Start        End    Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 2147485695 2147483648   1T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  2147485696 4294969343 2147483648   1T Linux filesystem
```

So far so good. Now if I'm trying to mount, I get an unspecified error, even in verbose mode. I've run fsck.ext4:

```
root@FluxCapacitor:/dev# fsck.ext4 /dev/sda1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
ext2fs_open2: Bad magic number in super-block
fsck.ext4: Superblock invalid, trying backup blocks...
fsck.ext4: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda

The superblock could not be read or does not describe a valid ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem.  If the device is valid and it really contains an ext2/ext3/ext4
filesystem (and not swap or ufs or something else), then the superblock
is corrupt, and you might try running e2fsck with an alternate superblock:
    e2fsck -b 8193 <device>
 or
    e2fsck -b 32768 <device>

Found a gpt partition table in /dev/sda
```

Same with:

```
root@FluxCapacitor:/dev# fsck /dev/sda1
root@FluxCapacitor:/dev# fsck.ext4 /dev/sda2
root@FluxCapacitor:/dev# fsck /dev/sda2
```

I've tried using any of the backup superblocks shown above and every other backup superblock, it won't work.

What am I not seeing here? Can somebody help me?

**Update** Here's the output of `lsblk -f`:

```
root@FluxCapacitor:~# lsblk -f
NAME        FSTYPE LABEL  UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                            
├─sda1                                                         
└─sda2                                                         
mmcblk1                                                        
├─mmcblk1p1 vfat   boot   52AA-6867                            /media/boot
└─mmcblk1p2 ext4   rootfs e139ce78-9841-40fe-8823-96a304a09859 /
```

As you can see, lsblk can't show the filesystem types. fdisk, which I used for partitioning on the other hand, can:

```
Command (m for help): p
Disk /dev/sda: 2.7 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 87E4647D-3D62-FC4B-BA74-91DFAF95E9A9

Device          Start        End    Sectors Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048 2147485695 2147483648   1T Linux filesystem
/dev/sda2  2147485696 4294969343 2147483648   1T Linux filesystem
```

Please note that I have only non-graphical options on an Ubuntu 18.04 ODROID HC2. Also I'm a non-native english speaker.

Also, I don't want to use the disk fur startup. I plant to put some home directories on it for different users of a backup system.

Comment: How do you try to mount? And what was the exact command you used to get the output from `e2fsck`?  Do you try to mount `sda`? You have to mount the partitions `sda1` and/or `sda2`.

Comment: I used `mount -t ext4 /dev/sda1 /mnt` and `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt`, same for `sda2`.

Comment: and ran `fsck /dev/sda1`, as well as `fsck.ext4 /dev/sda1`, same for /dev/sda2

Comment: since i ran it as root, i have root-privileges. also, i forgot to mention the mount-points, but it does not work. i am normally used to mount disks just like that.

Comment: You should always provide the used commands together with their output in your question, this is normally relevant information. Please edit your question accordingly. What does `lsblk -f` show?

Comment: thanks, mook765, for your interest, running lsblk brought my attention to the solution: i created partitions, i did not create a fs. Running `mkfs.ext4` fixed all the problems. Simply forgot to run that...